# A element not posting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a login form with an `<a>` element that I want to make a post request with. When I'm debugging the backend Django code it doesn't see the request method as a POST but rather as a GET.

HTML

```
  <form id="login">
      {% csrf_token %}
    {{login_form.as_p}}
      <a id="post" href="">post</a>
  </form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('a#post').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '#',
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Why is this?

Comment: Add the method attribute to the form: `method="post"`.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. I bet it shows as POST there

Comment: Try changing `type: 'POST'` to `method: 'POST'` (although this shouldn't be necessary, according to the docs)

Comment: An anchor with an empty href reloads the page, that's the GET request you're seeing, not the ajax call.

Comment: `type` should also work as it is an alias for `method`.

Comment: as @adeneo mentioned, make your event function has a parameter e then use `e.preventDefault()` if you are intending to use an anchor element only as a submit button. Besides, change the `type: "POST"` to `method: "post"` because in some cases, the type defines the accepting header type.

Comment: FYI: it doesn't matter in jQuery wether you use `method` or `type`, the first one was added in 1.9, but `type` is still an alias of `method`, they are **exactly** the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the default action of the anchor, which will just  reload the page when the `href` attribute is empty

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#post').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : window.location.href,
            data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```